# How to include BibDesk into TeXShop

Tags: biblatex, texshop, bibdesk

I am very new to `latex` and everything seems a little confusing. 
I put all my literature into `BibDesk`. Now I want to

- create a bibliography which needs to be in `TeXShop` for compilation
- somehow link (?) `BibDesk` to `TeXShop` in order for the `\cite{abc2001}` to work

I am also a little confused about all the differente formats one can save the literature into. I use a lof of information from `websites`. All of the times there are authors that can be quoted. However, when I add a new entry as `website`, I only get to enter `URL`, `last checked`, `year`, `month`, `keywords`- no author. 
Here is another one: `Inproceedings`. Is the `Book Title` the placeholder for the name of the conference, making the `title` the actual `article`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Have you read a beginner's guide on the topic bibliographies in LaTeX?

Comment: @TeXnician I will have a look at it. Wasn't aware that there is such thing. Can you post the link?

Comment: I haven't had a specific one in mind, but http://www.andy-roberts.net/writing/latex/bibliographies is quite good.

Comment: @TeXnician simply adding `\bibliographystyle{plain}`and `\bibliography{/Users/.../bibtex/bibliography.bib}` at the end of document does nothing. Nothing shows up (no error neither though). Further, I am not sure how to accomplish whats described in `Why won't LaTeX generate any output?`

Comment: you have to add the filename without the extension. it's `\bibliography{references}`. make sure it's either inside the project folder or a subfolder inside the project tree.

Comment: @naphaneal I changed it already without `.bib` extensions, copy & pasted the file into the folder (same level) where the `latex` document ist. no luck.

Comment: Have you also run bibtex?

Comment: @TeXnician thats what I wrote in a comment above. I am not sure how to do `Why won't LaTeX generate any output?` from the article you suggested...

Comment: You have to run the bibtex tool. Either select it from you editor's menu or run it in a terminal.

Comment: how and what did you install on your computer?

Comment: @naphaneal I got `MacTex` from here https://www.latex-project.org/get/ and installed it

Comment: Please have a look at [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864). You might also want to consult a TeX tutorial, many tutorials also cover the basics of bibliographies. There has been recent effort to make the Wikibook a reliable resource, and https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management is indeed quite good. Take some time to read these introductory texts and you'll find that you will understand the basics of bibliographies in TeX quite swiftly.